How to enable gutter indicators in vs code without any git configuration?
I want a gutter indicators in my open file in VS Code to show saved and modified line of code in file.
Screen shot of gutter indicators in Visual Studio 2019
I attach a image for example this screen shot is taken from classic Visual Studio 2019 IDE. In that this is default gutter indicators without setup git in project.
VS Code provide gutter indicators but for we setup and configure git repository.
But I need gutter indicator like classic Visual Studio 2019's gutter, without setup or configure git repository in VS Code.
